# recursive self join involving some loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

If `transfer_entry_no = 0` take the corresponding `posting_date` else
If `transfer_entry_no > 0` then search that number in `item_ledger_entry_no`. Now check if corresponding `transfer_entry_no = 0`. If this is true take the corresponding `posting_date`, and
else search that number in `item_ledger_entry_no`.

This loop continues until we get the corresponding `posting_date` when `transfer_enry_no = 0`.

Please help me to solve this using SQL

[image]

Comment: Microsoft sql server 2016

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and expected output.

Comment: Expected output:

Entry_no 1 : posting_date = 2018-01-13, Entry_no 2 : Posting_date = 2018-01-13, Entry_ no 3: posting_date =2018-01-15, Entry_no 4: posting_date = 2018-01-15